# django cannot delete an object from admin - coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found

Tags: python, django, unicode

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found
```

seems to be an easy solvable typeerror but I cannot solve this

I have models:

```
class QuizResult(models.Model):
   #fields ....
   def __unicode__(self):
         return u'%s' % self.title

class AnswerResult(models.Model):
   result = models.ForeignKey(related_name="result_combis1")
   def __unicode__(self):
         return u'Combi %s' % self.id

class AnswerResult2(models.Model):
   result = models.ForeignKey(related_name="result_combis2")
   def __unicode__(self):
         return u'Combi %s' % self.id
```

If I try to delete QuizResult Object, I am getting the error above. This is the traceback:

[image]

what am I missing?

Comment: Result object? Where is the Result model here?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini as you see, it is AnswerResult2, but It has the correct ``__unicode__`` method, right?

Comment: ID is a number. I think that causes a problem.

Comment: `u'Combi %s' % self.id` should work, `u'Combi ' + self.id` will fail with the same exception you are seeing. Are you sure you are using `%` and not `+`?

Comment: @doniyor Are you using python 3? If so, you should use a `__str__`  method instead of `__unicode__`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: python 3 has no `long` type

Comment: guys, I have it. there is another model which a child of AnswerResult2 via ForeignKey and it was returning a nude number in unicode method :) thanks all